# Выбрать регулярным выражением строку не ограниченную слешом

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно выбрать все слова, содержащие в своем составе слово reg с любым количеством букв и цифр спереди, кроме тех, которые ограниченны слешом.
Например
Чтобы подошли:

```
Amreg
1reg
reg
```

Но чтобы не подошли

```
/Amreg
/reg
/1reg
```

Помогите, пожалуйста(

Comment: что-то вроде `[^\/]*reg`?

Comment: Я уже так пробовал. Такая регулярка просто не учтет слеш. То есть выберется из /Amreg только Amreg. А нужно чтобы /Amreg вообще не подошло

Comment: а если так: `^[^\/]*reg`?

Comment: `/\b(?<!\/)\w*reg/`? `/\b(?<!\/)\w*reg\w*/`? `/\b(?<!\/)\w*reg\w*/u`?

Comment: @МихаилЧекавый на будущее, будьте добры указывать, для какого языка или редактора нужна регулярка.

Comment: Обязательно приводите пример реального текста и ожидаемый результат, иначе трудно дать однозначный ответ. Вы ищите соовпадения, чтобы сохранить как список или для замены? Какой язык программирования?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var txt = `
Amreg
/1reg

1reg
/reg
/Amreg

reg
`;
console.log(txt.match(/^([^/\s]*?reg)$/gm));
```

**`/^([^/\s]*?reg)$/gm`**

- `^` - от начала строки;
- `[^/\s]` - любой символ, кроме слеша, пробелов, табуляции и переносов строк;
- `*?reg` - совпадение до ближайшего *reg*;
- `()` - захват совпадения;
- `$` - конец строки.

Флаги: `g` - поиск по всему тексту, `m` - мультистрочный текст.

Comment: А вроде в вопросе не говорится, что слова по одному на строке...

Comment: @Qwertiy в вопросе много чего не говорится (партизаны жеж))), но дан пример данных, а там есть переносы.

Answer (score 0):

Если синтаксис позволяет, то можно воспользоваться предпросмотром назад:

```
\b(?!/)\w*reg\w*
```

---

Если нет, то можно сделать так

```
[^/](\w*reg\w*)
```

и брать первую группу.

Comment: вот и я о том же - если позволяет :)

Comment: @UModeL, дополнил.